# check the AND OR conditions for the return statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

how do i write this below expression?
I want to return false when the user is not admin AND when the user_id does not match the current_user_id OR the user_id is blank.

```
  def self.get_user_id(name) 
  current_user_id = User.current.id
  user_id = User.where("name=?" ,name).id
  admin = check_admin(current_user_id)
  return false if[(admin != true) && (user_id != current_user_id)] ||  user_id.blank?
   user_id
 end

 def self.check_admin(id)
 user = User.current 
 admin = Setting.find_by_key("admins").value
 return true  if admin.include?(user.login)
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby you do not need to use the `return` keyword explicitly, plus there are a couple mistakes in your code.  Try this:

```
def self.get_user_id(name) 
  current_user_id = User.current.id
  user_id = User.find_by(name: name)&.id
  admin = check_admin(current_user_id)
  admin && !(user_id.blank? || user_id != current_user_id)
end

def self.check_admin(id)
  user = User.current 
  admin = Setting.find_by_key("admins").value
  admin.include?(user.login)
end
```

Note: on Line 3 I make use of the ruby "safe operator", that assumes you are using Ruby >= 2.3.0.  If your ruby version is less than that you can use `user_id = User.find_by(name: name).try(:id)`